# FN Key broke, how to find out the keycode?

Tags: keyboard

I have the problem that the <kbd>FN</kbd> key on my keyboard broke, my keyboard fell down and now it’s not working anymore. Now I want to reassign the <kbd>FN</kbd> key with another key on my keyboard using a software. The problem is that the software is asking for a keycode to simulate they <kbd>FN</kbd> key on a different key.

How can I find out the keycode for the <kbd>FN</kbd> key on my keyboard without having to press the <kbd>FN</kbd> key which isn’t working anymore?
I checked the manual of my keyboard and the keycodes aren’t listed in there. Is there a way?

Comment: Fn keys on external keyboards are controlled by the keyboard firmware and not by the OS itself.  The Fn key is a modifier for media keys to make them produce a different code that matches the OS mappings.  It might be better to find the key mappings for the keys that you are trying to use from keyboard and remap them, however, it will not easy to keep remapping them over and over.  Probably best to invest in a new keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

FN keys are often handled directly by the keyboard's hardware rather than the operating system. This means that an FN key usually doesn't send a keycode to the OS in the same way other keys do.

You can try this:

1. Borrow another keyboard with FN keys
2. Open a terminal and run `xev`
3. Press various keys on the keyboard to see if the FN key produces any output. For most keyboards, the FN key itself will not generate a keycode, but the combination of FN and another key might

I just tried my FN key with `xev` and it is not generated any  response in `xev`. So my FN key is managed by the keyboard itself. Your keyboard can have different behavior, but I'm not really sure about that.

If the key is physically broken, I would consider swapping the key switches if your keyboard supports it. This is more common with mechanical keyboards.